# log4j / slf4j not able to read from properties file want working solution please

Tags: java, spring-boot, dialog, log4j, android-gradle-plugin

here below i used a sample app.ication to show the eraror, it never creates a log file

```
package com.example;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator;
public class logtester {
    static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(logtester.class);

    @Value("${log4j.appender.R.MaxFileSize}")

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PropertyConfigurator.configure("logProperties.properties");

        logger.debug("Sample debug message");
        logger.info("Sample info message");
        logger.warn("Sample warn message");
        logger.error("Sample error message");
        logger.fatal("Sample fatal message");
       // System.out.write("a2nd method");
        PropertyConfigurator.configure("application.properties");
        //System.out.write("weocme to usa");
        logger.debug("Sample debug message");
        logger.info("Sample info message");
        logger.warn("Sample warn message");
        logger.error("Sample error message");
        logger.fatal("Sample fatal message");
      //  System.out.write("a2nd method");


    }

}
```

the above is my main file and now i will post my prpoperties files

i used two to check if any of them works but nbuth did not

`application.properties` file

```
log4j.appender.FILE=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.FILE.File=TVK.log
log4j.appender.FILE.MaxFileSize=512KB
log4j.appender.FILE.MaxBackupIndex=3
log4j.appender.FILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.FILE.layout.conversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p - %m%og4j.appender.NotConsole=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.NotConsole.fileName=/some/path/to/a/fileName.log
log4j.appender.NotConsole.maxFileSize=20MB
```

another properties file : `log4jproperties.properties`

```
log4j.appender.FILE=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.FILE.File=TVK.log log4j.appender.FILE.MaxFileSize=512KB
log4j.appender.FILE.MaxBackupIndex=3
log4j.appender.FILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.FILE.layout.conversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p - %m%
log4j.appender.NotConsole=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.NotConsole.fileName=/some/path/to/a/fileName.log
log4j.appender.NotConsole.maxFileSize=20MB
log4j.appender.MAIN_LOG=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.MAIN_LOG.File=${catalina.base}/logs/webtop.log
log4j.appender.MAIN_LOG.layout=com.j256.ormlite.Log4JSimpleLayout
log4j.appender.MAIN_LOG.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.MAIN_LOG.MaxBackupIndex=5
log4j.appender.MAIN_LOG.append=true
log4j.rootCategory=ALL, MAIN_LOG
```

Comment: What do you believe that `@Value` annotation is doing?

Comment: The second property file seems to define a `log4j.rootCategory`, but it's supposed to be `log4j.rootLogger`. See javadoc of [`PropertyConfigurator`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/PropertyConfigurator.html). It only assign to appender `MAIN_LOG`, so why do you expect appenders `FILE` and `NotConsole` to be used? Loading the second file only updates those two, so again, why do you expect loading the second file to make any difference?

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple `PropertyConfigurator.configure()` methods (see https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/PropertyConfigurator.html).
The one you use looks for a file 'logProperties.properties' in the file system from the directory where you start the application.
If that file is packaged with the application, you should use the configure method taking the input stream:

```
PropertyConfigurator.configure(
    logtester.class.getResourceAsStream("/logProperties.properties");
```

Anyway, if log4j can't find the properties file, it should display some error:

```
log4j:ERROR Could not read configuration file [application.properties].
java.io.FileNotFoundException: application.properties (The system cannot find the file specified)
```

Do you have something similar?

Comment: yes i do i 've changed the path however it gives me 


Description Resource Path Location Type
The method getResourceAsStream(String) is undefined for the type logtester logtester.java /demo/src/main/java/com/example line 14 Java Problem

Comment: mmh, getResourceAsStream is a method of the class Class: do you see the '.class' just after your class name? and by the way make sure to use the proper case: LogTester would be better